# Using the MICR E13-B font with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

After a number of searches I can't seem to find an obvious answer to this so I'm hoping someone can help me.

What is the correct / most straightforward way to use the E13-B font for printing MICR checks?

Is there a specific font I need to install etc? I understand this is a high level question but I've found very little information on this. Thanks in advance,

Comment: if you have bought the font and installed it in the operating system you should be able to directly refer to it using the `fontspec` package in xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: Do you happen to know if any of the MICR fonts for printing checks are in the TeX repository? Or perhaps where I could find that out? I'm not having much luck with my searches today.

Comment: if you have a suitable non-tex font you can use it from xetex, you don't need a special tex version